# How add method to a function?

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

I've encountered on this exercise and I don't know how to solve CHALLENGE 3.

```js
/*Create a function PersonConstructor that uses the this keyword to save a single property onto its scope called
     greet. greet should be a function that logs the string 'hello'.*/
function PersonConstructor() {
  this.greet = function() {
    console.log('hello!');
  }
}

var simon = new PersonConstructor;

simon.greet(); // -> Logs 'hello'

/*** CHALLENGE 2 of 3 ***/
/*Create a function personFromConstructor that takes as input a name and an age. When called, the function will create
 person objects using the new keyword instead of the Object.create method.*/

function personFromConstructor(name, age) {
  var personObj = new PersonConstructor;
  personObj.name = name;
  personObj.age = age;
  return personObj;
}

var mike = personFromConstructor('Mike', 30);

console.log(mike.name); // -> Logs 'Mike'
console.log(mike.age); //-> Logs 30
mike.greet(); //-> Logs 'hello'

/*** CHALLENGE 3 of 3 ***/
/*Without editing the code you've already written, add an introduce method to the PersonConstructor function that logs
 "Hi, my name is [name]".*/
PersonConstructor.introduce = function() {
  console.log("Hi, my name is ");
};
mike.introduce(); // -> Logs 'Hi, my name is Mike' // doesn't work
```

How add method to a function PersonConstructor? `mike.introduce()` should log // -> Logs 'Hi, my name is Mike'

Comment: Have you tried adding it to the object's prototype? i.e. `PersonConstructor.prototype.introduce = function() {` and then something like `console.log("Hi, my name is" + this.name)`

Comment: @activedecay it is fine

Comment: @seesharper it's okay but needs lots of editing to make it legible. why would i want to read comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the function to the prototype of the class, so it will apply to all the objects. It can use `this.name` to access a property of the object.

```js
/*Create a function PersonConstructor that uses the this keyword to save a single property onto its scope called
     greet. greet should be a function that logs the string 'hello'.*/
function PersonConstructor() {
  this.greet = function() {
    console.log('hello!');
  }
}

var simon = new PersonConstructor;

simon.greet(); // -> Logs 'hello'

/*** CHALLENGE 2 of 3 ***/
/*Create a function personFromConstructor that takes as input a name and an age. When called, the function will create
 person objects using the new keyword instead of the Object.create method.*/

function personFromConstructor(name, age) {
  var personObj = new PersonConstructor;
  personObj.name = name;
  personObj.age = age;
  return personObj;
}

var mike = personFromConstructor('Mike', 30);

console.log(mike.name); // -> Logs 'Mike'
console.log(mike.age); //-> Logs 30
mike.greet(); //-> Logs 'hello'

/*** CHALLENGE 3 of 3 ***/
/*Without editing the code you've already written, add an introduce method to the PersonConstructor function that logs
 "Hi, my name is [name]".*/
PersonConstructor.prototype.introduce = function() {
  console.log("Hi, my name is " + this.name);
};
mike.introduce(); // -> Logs 'Hi, my name is Mike' // doesn't work
```